# Capturing pictures from multiple webcams (4 ones) using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I managed to get images from 4 identical USB webcams and save them in four different .avi files.

I use OpenCV 2.4. The source code for my application is compiled with:

```
g++ take_multicam_pictures.cpp -lcvaux -lopencv_highgui -lcv -lcxcore -o take_multicam_pictures
```

(in Ubuntu 10.04).

The problem is that I have to select each device, take a picture, and I have to release the device before a new one can be opened. And because of this, the number of frames/ second for each webcam is very low (like one frame/ second).

If I don't release each capture device before opening a new one, I get the following error:

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device
```

But I managed to start simultaneously the laptop webcam, and one external webcam. Here is the output from `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Hama Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0ac8:3450 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0ac8:3450 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0ac8:3450 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0ac8:3450 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is the code I used for getting pictures from all four webcams, and save them in four different video files.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 
IplImage* frame1 = 0;

int record_cam(int dev, CvVideoWriter *writer)
{ 
    CvCapture* capture1 = cvCaptureFromCAM(dev);    // select device 

    cvGrabFrame(capture1);                          // capture a frame

    frame1 = cvRetrieveFrame(capture1);             // retrieve the captured frame

    cvWriteFrame(writer, frame1);                   // write captured           frame to .avi file  

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture1);                    // release the capture device
}

// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() 
{
    CvVideoWriter *writer1 = 0;         //create writer device that allows us to place frames in video file
    CvVideoWriter *writer2 = 0;
    CvVideoWriter *writer3 = 0;
    CvVideoWriter *writer4 = 0;
    int isColor = 1;                    //video properties
    int fps     = 3; 
    int frameW  = 640;                  //webcam dimension
    int frameH  = 480;

    writer1 = cvCreateVideoWriter("out1.avi",CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'),fps,cvSize(frameW,frameH),isColor);
    writer2 = cvCreateVideoWriter("out2.avi",CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'),fps,cvSize(frameW,frameH),isColor);
    writer3 = cvCreateVideoWriter("out3.avi",CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'),fps,cvSize(frameW,frameH),isColor);
    writer4 = cvCreateVideoWriter("out4.avi",CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'),fps,cvSize(frameW,frameH),isColor);

    int nFrames = 20, i = 0, key;       //capture 20 frames from each webcam and saves them in video files (out1.avi, out2.avi ...)

    for(i=0;i<nFrames;i++)
    {
        record_cam(1, writer1);         //capture frames from each web cam and writes them in different .avi files
        record_cam(2, writer2);
        record_cam(3, writer3);
        record_cam(4, writer4);
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer1);
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer2);
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer3);
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not very experienced in camera capture, but as I know, OpenCV was not written with good input capabilities. Its main strength is image processing. For a real app, both image input and user interface should be written with dedicated libraries. highgui was meant as a help for rapid prototyping, and not for production. Many questions here on SO are related to the limitations of the input/display/output of OpenCV

Comment: @vasile Thank you for answering. Can you tell me some c/c++ libraries that have good input capabilities (like opening multiple USB web cams, and save frames into separate .avi files, i really don't need image processing)? I am not looking for user interface libraries (at least for now). Maybe later, i will have to send live images to another computer on the internet.

Comment: Chech this out. I did not use it myself, but I heard very positive reviews about it http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/

Comment: @sammy: videoInput is for Windows - the question mentions Ubuntu as OS.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get comes from the USB bus. It basically tells you that the **dataload** on your USB connection is **too high**. The reason are the default settings for opening a stream of a webcam in OpenCV.

The simplest workaround is to use a **separate USB bus for every camera** you want to attach. 
The implementation in OpenCV (at least 2.4.3.2) lacks support for specifying the framerate correctly for a lot of webcams so I patched the sources for my own purposes to be able to have more than one webcam.

You can find more details in my **[answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4909/using-2-webcams-simultaneously/?answer=7228#post-id-7228)** to a question on the OpenCV Q&A site.

Comment: Hi, `separate USB bus for every camera ` how can you do this?

Comment: Every USB port is connected to one. You have to identify the ports leading to different USB buses. Then connect the cameras to ports leading to different USB buses. `lsusb` should give you the wanted information, or the device manager in windows. If you only have one bus, buy an USB PCI card.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a program to capture pictures from multiple webcams with openCV and Tkinter for the GUI. Afterwords the pictures made can be pushed in a movie.

[Link to my github page where you can find source code and exe file](https://github.com/KarimAchaibou/multiple-webcam-capturing)