# how can i open 4 cameras Simultaneously

Tags: opencv

how many camera i can open in opencv?
I can just open 2 ones but i need to open 4 cameras,i have to close 2 ones and open another 2 ones every time.
the problem is in captured image i have a img with cols:320 and rows:0

```
            VideoCapture cam0(0);
            Sleep(1000);
            VideoCapture cam1(1);
            Sleep(1000);
            VideoCapture cam2(2);
            Sleep(1000);
            VideoCapture cam3(3);
            Sleep(1000);
```

and retrieve image in a loop

```
                cam0.retrieve(src,0);
                if(src.empty())
                    cout<<"error in rec data..."<<endl;
                imshow("Cam0",src);



                cam1.retrieve(src,0);
                if(src.empty())
                    cout<<"error in rec data..."<<endl;
                imshow("Cam1",src);


                cam2.retrieve(src,0);
                if(src.empty())
                    cout<<"error in rec data..."<<endl;
                imshow("Cam2",src);



                cam3.retrieve(src,0);
                if(src.empty())
                    cout<<"error in rec data..."<<endl;
                imshow("Cam3",src);
```

it works for 2 first camera but for 2 second ones i have an error "bad flag"

thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737606/capturing-pictures-from-multiple-webcams-4-ones-using-opencv, which might answer your question? The original poster seems to have done it for four cameras, although ran into another error.

Comment: thank you blochwave,the problem was that you mentioned,i have limitation in usb bus,BW in usb 2.0 is 480 Mbit/s but for 640*480 image with 3 channels and 8 bit and in 60 seconds is more than 420 Mbit/s 420/480

Comment: Did you try to connect those USB cameras to USB 3.0 hub connected to USB 3.0 port? I didn't test this solution, but it's worth to try.
Also you can install additional USB controller in the computer and connect there two remaining cameras.

Answer (score 0):

```
 VideoCapture cap0(0);
 VideoCapture cap1(1);
...

// later:
cap0.read(frame0);
cap1.read(frame1);
...
```

but reality sucks here, again. the usb bandwidth of a single hub is just enough for 1 cam, if you plug 2 or more into 1 bus, you'll saturate it. you can still reduce the framesize,

```
cap0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
cap0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
```

and pray, that you got 2 seperate hubs ( try front/back )